# C++ Builder question

Tags: c++, ide, c++builder

I installed the package BusinessSkin, in Borland C++ 5.0 and i works fine, and after 2 days i see it just open a header from \VLC\Clipboard.hpp and Borland C++ 5.0 header and it give me an error Declaration Terminated incoretly

```
#ifndef ClipbrdHPP
#define ClipbrdHPP

#pragma delphiheader begin
#pragma option push -w-
#pragma option push -Vx
#include <Graphics.hpp> // Pascal unit
#include <Classes.hpp>  // Pascal unit
#include <Messages.hpp> // Pascal unit
#include <Windows.hpp>  // Pascal unit
#include <SysInit.hpp>  // Pascal unit
#include <System.hpp>   // Pascal unit

//-- user supplied -----------------------------------------------------------

namespace Clipbrd
{
//-- type declarations -------------------------------------------------------
class DELPHICLASS TClipboard;
class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TClipboard : public Classes::TPersistent 
{
    typedef Classes::TPersistent inherited;

private:
    int FOpenRefCount;
    HWND FClipboardWindow;
    bool FAllocated;
    bool FEmptied;
    void __fastcall Adding(void);
    void __fastcall AssignGraphic(Graphics::TGraphic* Source);
    void __fastcall AssignPicture(Graphics::TPicture* Source);
    void __fastcall AssignToBitmap(Graphics::TBitmap* Dest);
    void __fastcall AssignToMetafile(Graphics::TMetafile* Dest);
    void __fastcall AssignToPicture(Graphics::TPicture* Dest);
    AnsiString __fastcall GetAsText();
    int __fastcall GetFormatCount(void);
    Word __fastcall GetFormats(int Index);
    void __fastcall SetAsText(const AnsiString Value);
    void __fastcall SetBuffer(Word Format, void *Buffer, int Size);
    void __fastcall WndProc(Messages::TMessage &Message);

protected:
    virtual void __fastcall AssignTo(Classes::TPersistent* Dest);

public:
    virtual void __fastcall Assign(Classes::TPersistent* Source);
    void __fastcall Clear(void);
    void __fastcall Close(void);
    Classes::TComponent* __fastcall GetComponent(Classes::TComponent* Owner, Classes::TComponent* Parent
        );
    unsigned __fastcall GetAsHandle(Word Format);
    int __fastcall GetTextBuf(char * Buffer, int BufSize);
    bool __fastcall HasFormat(Word Format);
    void __fastcall Open(void);
    void __fastcall SetComponent(Classes::TComponent* Component);
    void __fastcall SetAsHandle(Word Format, unsigned Value);
    void __fastcall SetTextBuf(char * Buffer);
    __property AnsiString AsText = {read=GetAsText, write=SetAsText};
    __property int FormatCount = {read=GetFormatCount, nodefault};
    __property Word Formats[int Index] = {read=GetFormats};
public:
    #pragma option push -w-inl
    /* TPersistent.Destroy */ inline __fastcall virtual ~TClipboard(void) { }
    #pragma option pop

public:
    #pragma option push -w-inl
    /* TObject.Create */ inline __fastcall TClipboard(void) : Classes::TPersistent() { }
    #pragma option pop

};


//-- var, const, procedure ---------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE Word CF_PICTURE;
extern PACKAGE Word CF_COMPONENT;
extern PACKAGE TClipboard* __fastcall Clipboard(void);
extern PACKAGE TClipboard* __fastcall SetClipboard(TClipboard* NewClipboard);

}   /* namespace Clipbrd */
#if !defined(NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE)
using namespace Clipbrd;
#endif
#pragma option pop  // -w-
#pragma option pop  // -Vx

#pragma delphiheader end.
//-- end unit ----------------------------------------------------------------
#endif  // Clipbrd
```

I moved on a different PC there i had c++ builder 5.0 and 2009, i just installed the library and it give a similary error but in other unit, why?

The library works in Delphi. Initialy i compiled the library that have about 50-60 units, and works, also on installing.

Comment: what is the exact error? (what line/file) IME, this error is usually because of a macro that isn't defined. and that should give you a hint as to where to look.

Comment: also, if multiple versions are installed on the same PC, make sure the search paths are set up correctly.

Comment: solved? please, provide more info.